# Create environment variable via Winform application, very slow

Tags: c#, winforms, environment-variables

In a Winform application, I create some Environment Variable (Windows 7). The creation works but it’s very slow, around 9sec to create one.

I use this code :

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(
    variableName, 
    value, 
    EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine
);
```

Is it strange, isn’t it ?

**See the log :**

```
5/01/2012 08:22:09 : MyVar1
5/01/2012 08:22:18 : MyVar2
5/01/2012 08:22:26 : MyVar3
```

Comment: Do you really need them or can't you have them in *Application Settings*

Comment: @V4Vendetta yes need them. The application, is a kind of installer to set environment (and set these variables is a part of the job) for the main application.

Comment: What are the values for `[variableName]` and `[value]`? Are you doing anything else between logs? Some code would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Check what you have running, multiple running processes means that you could have a long delay, close all the apps you are running (Chrome, IE, Notepad, etc) and run the app to see how long it takes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    stopwatch.Restart();
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(
        "Variable " + i,
        i.ToString(),
        EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " Variable:" + i);
}
```

That piece of code (with all apps on my machine closed) executed each `SetEnvironmentVariable` call in < 300ms.  Also, consider the use of `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process` as it will be faster than setting the variable for the whole machine.

According to Environment class sources (can be found [here](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Environment@cs/1305376/Environment@cs), line 864), after setting user/machine scope environment variable, it calls native SendMessageTimeout function to notify any process about changes in environment. Here is excerpt:

```
IntPtr r = Win32Native.SendMessageTimeout(
    new IntPtr(Win32Native.HWND_BROADCAST), 
    Win32Native.WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 
    IntPtr.Zero, 
    "Environment", 
    0, 
    1000, 
    IntPtr.Zero);
```

So 1000 milliseconds (1 second) timeout is given to any recipient to process the message. E.g. if 5 of them fail to process it, you could have up to 5 seconds delay. More about SendMessageTimeout can be found in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

-- Credit to [Dmitry](https://superuser.com/questions/565771/setting-user-environment-variables-is-very-slow)

Comment: I had the same issue, and resorted to using an external program to set the env variable (in the background). It is a hack but at least my program is not slowed down (in VBA you can't really run this in a background thread): http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/tutorials/article.php/c10849/Setting-a-System-Environment-Variable.htm